# Fix ESLint: Insert `·`(prettier/prettier) on WebStorm

Tags: eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

For the following react code I get the following error:

When I run ESLint using the `--fix` flag on my code base, I get an error that reads:

```
ESLint: A space is required before closing bracket(react/jsx-tag-spacing)

ESLint: Insert `.` (prettier/prettier)
```

[image]

Didn't find any documentation about this error - How do I fix that?

Note: I'm using WebStorm - not sure it is related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

##### This Question is a Couple Years Old, but It Deserves a Better Answer & Explanation

#### [`PRETTIER/PRETTIER`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prettier)

`Prettier/Prettier` isn't the error, its exactly what it says it is, it is **Prettier**. The rule comes from a plugin that you installed called **[eslint-plugin-prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prettier)**. What the Plugin, and the Prettier/Prettier rule do, is they execute prettier through ESLint, or through the Prettier/Prettier rule really. ESLint is capable of Linting, and formatting code, which cause issues with prettier, which also formats code, but does say in a way that is described as "Bias". Devs often opt to use both, so they can take advantage of what a linter and bias formatter both offer, which is a topic beyond the scope of this answer.

To harmonize ESLint, and prettier, the **"eslint-plugin-prettier"** extension uses the `Prettier/Prettier` rule to execute prettier through ESLint, so that any problems that occur after formatting with prettier, and linting/fixing with ESLint, show up as an error reported by Prettier/Prettier. The errors should be interpreted as a conflict between Prettier & ESLint, or between Prettier & a different ESLint-Plugin. Generally, the issue is that ESLint and Prettier are not configured harmoniously, and a change needs to be made to, either the `.prettierrc` configuration, or the `.eslintrc.*` configuration.

---

#### The Actual Error

The actual error, as stated above, is not Prettier/Prettier. The reason Prettier/ prettier showed up in the message is because it is the rule that is reporting the error, but the actual error is the part that reads:

###### *`"A space is required before a closing bracket."`*

The error message is in reference to a rule added by another plugin, which maybe causing a conflict with a prettier a rule, that at the time (4/2020) was active, but [the rule was deprecated](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#deprecated-jsx-brackets), in favor of this rule: **[`--jsx-bracket-same-line`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-line)**

The actual error that occurred though, was prettier saying, my configuration doesn't like how the react/jsx plugin rule is fixing (or formatting) the code.

The React plugin rule that prettier is complaining about in the error message is **[`JSX-tag-spacing`](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-tag-spacing.md)**.

And that, just FYI, is what that error you are getting is all about. You have a couple different plugins, linting a code base that's using a framework, on top of a language, with embedded HTML. Any situation like that is going to require that you fine tune your development environment, linter, debugger, and what ever other tools.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.
Now Im not sure why it it so common to use prettier and eslint together? seems those tools are not really fit together. eslint give you freedom to format however you want, prettier dont - so why both?

Comment: Personally, I dropped prettier, deleted the extensions, and removed the dev-dependances from any of my repo-branches. ESLint is just too damn good now. Prettier does offer somthing that ESLint doesn't though, which is bias formatting. Because prettier is bias (meaning it chooses how it feels code should be formatted) it can format things that ESLint cannot. Another advatage to a bias formatter is if you work with a team, the rules are set, no one can complain because the way the code is formatted can hardly be configured, and it takes hardly anytime to configure.

Comment: Before ESLint merged with JSHint, and TSLint, it had some holes it didn't cover, and prettier came to the rescue, but now ESLint handles things like brace fromatting, and highly customizable indenting, and block level formatting (all things it didn't do well before). So IMO, if you want the advantage of a bias formatter, just use prettier, if you want to customize how your code is formatted use ESLint. Personally, I will always choose the linter over the bias formatter unless an employer makes me do otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

It's asking you to insert a single white space... You can enable **Other/Spaces/In empty tag** in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | HTML** to get spaces added on code auto-formatting

Comment: Strange error message from prettier - "when we write `.` we mean space..."